# persian week in c# returning wrong number

Tags: c#

want to get DayOfWeek in persianCalnder but it is always same as Georgian Calender,

```
   DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
   PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();

 var  geDayOfWeek= today.DayOfWeek;             
 var pcDayOfWeek=pc.GetDayOfWeek(today);
```

why the value of geDayOfWeek and pcDayOfWeek are always the same ? persian week starts in Saturday not Monday , so for example Sunday should be 2 not 0 .

any solution to get day number in Persian calendar ?

i need this to calculate start date and end date of week in Persian Calendar not Georgian Calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a extention method for DateTime to get Persion Day Of Week

```
public static class DateTimeHelper
{
    public static PersianDayOfWeek PersionDayOfWeek(this DateTime date)
    {
        switch (date.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Shanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Yekshanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Doshanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Seshanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Charshanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Panjshanbe;
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                return PersianDayOfWeek.Jome;
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    public enum PersianDayOfWeek
    {
        Shanbe=1,
        Yekshanbe=2,
        Doshanbe=3,
        Seshanbe=4,
        Charshanbe=5,
        Panjshanbe=6,
        Jome=7
    }
}
```

You can use it like this :

PersianDayOfWeek DoW = DateTime.Now.PersionDayOfWeek();